# How to solve $\beta^{-1}\pi^{2016}\beta = \alpha$ where $\alpha$, $\beta$ are given permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, cyclic-decomposition, permutation-cycles

I am given two permutations

$$\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 3 & 11 & 9 & 12 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix} $$
and
$$\beta = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 6 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 12 & 1 & 11 & 9 & 2 & 3 & 10 & 8\end{pmatrix}. $$
Now I need to find a **cyclic structure** of permutation $\pi$, for which holds
$$\beta^{-1}\pi^{2016}\beta = \alpha$$ and then **find two distinct solutions**.

---

My approach was to first write the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as cycles. Then I calculated $\pi^{2016} = \beta \alpha \beta^{-1}$ and I got
$$\pi^{2016} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &10&7\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&6&12&4&11\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5&9&8\end{pmatrix}.$$

Since $\pi^{2016}$ has a $5$-cycle and $2016 = 2015 + 1$ and $5 \mid 2015$, $\pi$ has the same $5$-cycle. But because $2016$ is divisible by $3$ and $6$, $\pi$ cannot have a $3$ or $6$-cycle. Using a theorem that says that cycle of length $L = mn$ raised to $m$-th power, decomposes into $m$ cycles of length $n$, no other $L$'s, $L < 7$ can decompose into two $3$-cycles. I am kinda stuck here...

---

The problem is that as a math major we did not do any sorts of such things yet, I assume because I did not take number theory. And in algebra we were just doing proof over proof and no concrete task.

I assume this task is a very easy one but please understand my situation.

Comment: So $\pi^{2016}=\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$. What is $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$?

Comment: Yeah, I calculated that. But I do not know what to do next. I know there is something about solving Diophantine equation for powers, but I do not know what, because I have no material to look into plus doing a Google search with "permutations" in it always returns the wrong ones (the permutations with combinations). Or were you asking me to post the answer? I assumed it was just a hint, but will post anyways.

Comment: You learn mathematics most effectively by performing one's own investigations, not by performing Google searches $\ddot\frown$. If you have a permutation in $S_{12}$ could you rapidly work out its 2016-th power; and how would the cycle structure of the new permutation relate to the old?

Comment: Well, I know that if you raise a permutation to lcm of cycle lengths you get the identity, so raising the permutation to lcm+1 yields the same one back. I am not sure on how to calculate the $2016$-th power in $S_{12}$ (maybe I am too focused on order of $S_{12}$ being $12!$...)

Comment: I mean I know how to calculate powers, I do not know how to invert the thing, meaning I know how to solve $\pi = \alpha^{2016}$ but I have no clue about $\pi^{2016} = \alpha$, solving both for $\pi$.

Comment: Certainly $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}$ has a 5-cycle and two 3-cycles. That's a pity: if it had turned out to be just $(2\,6\,12\,4\,11)$ then it would be easy to find such a $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, agree. But how would one approach this problem?

Comment: How about investigating the 2016-th (or more generally the $n$-th power) of permutations with one non-trivial cycle.

Comment: Indeed, I just got an idea while smoking a cig... Gosh, smoking does help with maths! I will edit the question...

Comment: Okay, the idea is next. We have a 5 cycle and same 5 cycle is in $\pi$, because $\pi^{2016} = \pi^{2015}\pi$ and since $5 \mid 2015$, the cycle disappears in $2015$-th power. As per the 3 cycles, I need to find some way to use the fact that a cycle of length $L = mn$ raised to $m$-th power, decomposes into $m$ cycles of length $n$ (and again using some modular arithmetic). I think that I am on the right way...

Comment: For 3 cycles I have a problem because $2016$ is divisible with $3$ and $6$, so $\pi$ does not have a $3$ or $6$ cycle but other lengths of cycles cannot decompose into two $3$-cycles...

Comment: Yes, that's a bit of a problem....